# Query to fetch table names from dba_tables in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to fetch table names from dba_tables using join with dba_tab_statistics.

```
select table_name 
from dba_tables a,
     dba_tab_statistics b 
where a.owner like 'Owner' and a.table_name not like '%TMP'
  and a.LAST_ANALYZED IS NOT NULL and a.table_name = b.table_name
  and b.stattype_locked IS NULL;
```

This query doesn't give distinct table names. What changes are required ?

Comment: Simply do `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use either of them:

```
SELECT a.table_name
  FROM dba_tables a, 
        dba_tab_statistics b
 WHERE     a.owner LIKE 'Owner'
       AND a.table_name NOT LIKE '%TMP'
       AND a.LAST_ANALYZED IS NOT NULL
       AND a.table_name = b.table_name
       AND b.stattype_locked IS NULL
 group by a.table_name ;
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.table_name
  FROM dba_tables a, 
        dba_tab_statistics b
 WHERE     a.owner LIKE 'Owner'
       AND a.table_name NOT LIKE '%TMP'
       AND a.LAST_ANALYZED IS NOT NULL
       AND a.table_name = b.table_name
       AND b.stattype_locked IS NULL ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution :

```
SELECT table_name
  FROM dba_tables a
 WHERE owner LIKE 'Owner'
   AND table_name NOT LIKE '%TMP'
   AND LAST_ANALYZED IS NOT NULL
   AND exists (SELECT 0 
              FROM dba_tab_statistics b
              WHERE a.table_name = b.table_name
              AND b.stattype_locked IS NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Only thing is taking more time i.e. 15-20 minutes

Comment: select a.table_name
  from dba_tab_statistics a, dba_tables b
 where a.owner like 'SCHEMA1'
   and a.table_name not like '%TMP'
   and a.table_name not in
       ('TABLE1', 'TABLE2', 'TABLE3')
   and a.stattype_locked IS NULL and b.temporary = 'N'
 group by a.table_name
 order by max(a.NUM_ROWS) desc;